# Does Windows expose SMB NativeOS or Nativelanman for a network share in the win32 api?

Tags: windows, winapi

SMB's session setup packet contains both a NativeOS and NativeLanMan field that describe both host and client.
I have a need to determine if a network share is SAMBA or Windows Server to avoid a bug.
I know both of these do set unique fields for the setup packet but I am at a loss of finding a win32 api that may expose this info.

Comment: Did you want to check the network types? See [`WNetGetNetworkInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetnetworkinformationa) and [Network types](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/shared/wnnc.h#L32)

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Wouldn't both SAMBA and Windows Server shares show up as WNNC_NET_SMB?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. In the title, you want to get NativeOS and NativeLanMan. and in the text, you want to determine whether the network share is SAMBA or Windows Server. This is the structure([`SESSION_INFO_2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/ns-lmshare-session_info_2)) I can only find about getting info of LAN Manager.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Sorry that I'm confusing. I want to determine if a SMB network share is either samba or Windows Server hosted. I referenced NativeOS and NativeLanMan only because these are two fields named in the SMB protocol and indicate that the Windows client at least received information on what the SMB host is. I don't see how I can fetch samba or Windows Server through the functions you suggested unforuantely.